# Using Python to manipulate 31-bits

Tags: python, binary, hex, python-3.4, pyserial

I have a specification which outlines how instructions should be sent over serial.

Currently I am crafting the packets that will go over the connection.

One segment of the packet, requires a 32-bit (4 byte) binary number. 
The first 31-bits are 'data' and the last bit is merely a flag.

So, The max decimal number that could fit in data is: 2147483647 (2^31). Data could never be bigger than this, Cool!

My problem, is how do I go about encoding the data to 31-bits binary, then setting the final bit to enable the flag?

Say my data is `7AAAAAAA` what is the desirable way of converting this to 31 bit binary then adding 1 or a 0 to the end?

**Edit - I'm Using Python 3.4**

Comment: Look into the `struct` module plus the bit-modifying operator `|`.

Comment: using `struct` in this case might be problematic since your data number is not 4-bit integer. Struct operates on full bytes only.

Comment: For hard-coded data, you can do stuff like `(0x7AAAAAAA<<1) | flag`. But in any case, you should use [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to handle the conversion to bytes in an endian-aware way.

Comment: Bit-fiddling in Python can be a little tricky because we don't have unsigned integers, and our integers are not of a fixed byte length. However, that's really not a problem with careful use of `struct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use binary shift to add your flag to a number:

```
a = 0x7AAAAAAA                # 2058005162 = 0b1111010101010101010101010101010
f = 1                         # 1 = 0b1

packet = a + (f << 31)        # a + 0b10000000000000000000000000000000
bin(packet)                   # 0b11111010101010101010101010101010
```

To unpack you can use mask and binary AND like this:

```
mask = (1 << 31) - 1          # 2147483647 = 0b1111111111111111111111111111111
a = packet & mask             # 2058005162 = 0b1111010101010101010101010101010
f = packet >> 31              # 1 = 0b1
```

Comment: or similarly `packet = (a << 1) | f` if you want the flag at the end

Answer (score 1):

The only thing which comes to my mind is operation on strings

Say we have two variables:

```
>>> data = '7AAAAAAA'
>>> flag = '1'
```

Convert the data hex to number

```
>>> num = int(data, 16)
>>> num
2058005162
```

Convert the number to string binary representation:

```
>>> bin_num = bin(num)
>>> bin_num
'0b1111010101010101010101010101010'
```

Append flag to the end

```
>>> bin_num += flag
>>> bin_num
'0b11110101010101010101010101010101'
```

Evaluate string to get number and convert back to hex or whatever you need:

```
>>> eval(bin_num)
4116010325
```

**#edit1**

In order to extend the value to 4-bytes you can use:

```
>>> final_val = eval(bin_num)
>>> int.to_bytes(final_val, 4, 'big')
b'\xf5UUU'
```

**#edit2**

```
def convert(data, flag):
    with_flag = eval(bin(int(data, 16)) + flag)
    return int.to_bytes(with_flag, 4, 'big')

def unconvert(byte_data):
    bin_str = bin(int.from_bytes(byte_data, 'big'))
    flag = bin_str[-1]
    data = bin_str[:-1]
    return (hex(eval(data)), flag)
```

Comment: This would work, I could use `binascii` to encode the binary data. However, If data was just `FF` the binary representation would not be big enough, Maybe a way to pad data to always use a 31-bit binary representation?

Comment: you can use `int.to_bytes(final_number, 4, 'big')` in order to use big-endian, and extend to 4 bytes

Answer (score 0):

See if this works, similar to other answers but accounts for original bit length.

Define the final number of bits

```
>>> bits = 16
```

Start with a bytes literal

```
>>> a = b'10'
```

Convert to an `int`

```
>>> b = int(a, base = 16)
```

Shift left to the required bit length

```
>>> shift = bits - b.bit_length()
>>> c = b << shift
```

Add the *flag*

```
>>> d = c | 1

>>> 
>>> a
b'10'
>>> b
16
>>> c
32768
>>> d
32769

>>> bin(b)
'0b10000'
>>> bin(c)
'0b1000000000000000'
>>> bin(d)
'0b1000000000000001'
>>>
```